# Ring current decreases magnetic field?

Tags: electric-current

Right to my question:

In Kelley book on Ionosphere I found:  "*since ions are deflected toward dusk and electrons toward dawn, a net duskward current exists in a thin sheet (extending also out of the plane of the diagram) where the force balance occurs. The secondary magnetic field generated by this current sheet is parallel to the earth’s field in the region between the earth and the current sheet and is antiparallel to the earth’s magnetic field in the solar wind. This magnetic field cancels the earth’s field on the sunward side of the boundary and increases the value of the magnetic field inside the current sheet.*"

[image: Kelley]

It is written clearly that inside the current sheet (to the Earth) the magnetic field is increased.

Why then when I consider Dst index, it is written everywhere:

"*During the development of so-called geomagnetic storms, charged particles are injected into the Van Allen belts from the outer magnetosphere, giving rise to a sharp increase in the ring current, and a corresponding decrease in the Earth's equatorial magnetic field*"

or

"*while the subsequent increase of the ring current leads to major decrease of the surface field*"

My question: if ring current creates additional magnetic field at the same direction as main magnetic field (just by right-hand rule), why ring current decrease main field and not increase it? And thus why Dst index is negative?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The ring current is not the same phenomena as the ionospheric current described in the text.

Comment: I had this thought... So you mean that Kelley's book describes the ionospheric current, but ring current is that from Van Allen ring? What is then the difference if in both cases we deal with Solar wind trapped by Earth's magnetic field? Thank you.

Comment: The ring current is a dusk-to-dawn flow of mostly H+ and O+ (from memory) that is due to particle drift a non-uniform magnetic field (gradient-curvature drift).  Have a look at http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/1999RG900009/pdf if you have access, it's a good review article on the subject.  There is a good text by Kivelson and Russell that was of great help to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you show here does not illustrate the ring-current, which exists due to the gradient-curvature drift of high-energy ions creating a magnetic field in the *opposite* direction to the internal magnetic field. Hence, a stronger ring current reduces the measured geomagnetic field measured at ground-based installations. Here is a better image -

[image]

The image you show in your question illustrates the Chapman-Ferraro current (marked in this picture as the "Magnetopause current"), which is present at the Earth's magnetopause. In the MHD limit, this current can be thought of as the current that provides the $\mathbf{J} \times \mathbf{B}$ force which opposes the $\nabla p$ force at the magnetopause. In the particle perspective, it forms due to the opposite drifting patterns of ions and electrons (as shown in the first image).